# Got fired, accepted an old offer, now they are doing a background check, what should I do?

Tags: job-offer, termination, background-check, relocation

I received an offer to relocate abroad when I was working for some company. I got fired some time after receiving this offer. Then, I accepted the relocation offer without disclosing I had been recently fired.

The new company has now sent me a contract which states that the offer could be rescinded after a background check. Considering it is a relocation, I'd have to sell and leave everything I have here, it is going to be a massive move.

Should I tell them I was fired from my previous job? Would that come up in the background check? I never lied to them or anything, as all the interviews happened when I was still working.

Comment: What is your locale?

Comment: @rath I live in Brazil right now, the offer is in Europe.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere As far as I remember, they didn't ask that anytime explicity, but during interviews I commented about what was my current job then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is a "criminal background check" or "police background check" it won't come up as they will only be searching the police database.  This will be obvious as the wording will be one of the two.  Not all jurisdictions have access to such checks and what is disclosable in such checks (even if they can be done) will vary greatly as well.

A "background check" can be anything.  In your case it is most likely conducted through a third party or they do it themselves.  One of the first things they will check is your employment history.  If you have been terminated you can pretty much guarantee it will be mentioned (although depending on locale it might not).  If there is a verbal questionnaire and the background checker is half competent they will find out.  Other things they may check for could be education (did you really get honors at that uni like you claimed) or sometimes even a credit background check (are you likely to be a risk to be tempted to commit fraud).  Background checks can be intrusive depending on the context.

You are far better off letting them know now before dragging your family (if you have one) through something that could end up being a very difficult time for all.

Here's a couple of links to the background check company used by our organization and what they can reveal:
https://www.hireright.com/background-check-faq
https://www.hireright.com/apac/background-check-faq/answers/what-does-a-background-check-reveal

Answer (score 3):

I can't imagine how the firing could be found out via a background check.  Chances are, they're going to search your criminal record only, possibly your credit history.    If they check references, you'd want to be aware of what they may say, if they would disclose it.

I can't see how they can fault you for it -- the way I understand you, you applied for, and got offered the job before the firing, so there was no reason to disclose it.  Unless you filled out a new application and specifically answered "No" to the "Did you get fired?" question, it's irrelevant.

Comment: Background checks usually cover employment background checks as well and a termination would definitely come up.

Answer (score 0):

Probably wouldn’t show up in a background check, but even if it did: so? Did you get fired for something illegal or unethical? If not, I wouldn’t sweat it.